# Expected Value of Unique Colors of Marbles

Tags: probability

I have a machine that produces *n* marbles that are each randomly colored one of *n* potential colors.

n=1, E[# unique colors]=1

n=2, E[# unique colors]=.5*2 + .5*1 = 1.5

etc.

What is the expected number of unique colors that I would see in set of marbles when it is set to produce *n* marbles.?

Answer (score 1):

Every color has a probability of $1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n}$
to show up. This amounts in an expectation of $n\left[1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]$
colors that show up.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The trick here is to look at the problem out of the perspective of the colours. Not that of the productions.

Comment: This can be thought of as a place n balls into n buckets problem. How many buckets are empty? The probability that we miss a particular bucket is (n-1)/n. So after n placements, the probability that we missed the bucket is ((n-1)/n)^n. So the probability that we placed something into the bucket is 1-((n-1)/n)^n.

Comment: Yes, you are using the same principle there.